# Arrays inside a loop

Tags: php, arrays

I have a loop, at one point in this loop i need to sum different amounts wich represent how much the project has been funded. my problem is for the first project the amounts are ok but for the next project, first project amount is added to second project.

The loop:

```
//money bar progress 1 (li_montant_recu=0 OR li_montant_recu=1) 
$p_one=$db->query("SELECT * FROM leve_invest WHERE (li_montant_recu=0 OR li_montant_recu=1) AND li_leve_id='".$l_r["l_id"]."'");

while($p_one_r=$p_one->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    $amount_p_one[]=$p_one_r["li_montant_hors_com"];
}

$p_one_sum=round((array_sum($amount_p_one) / $l_r["m_s"]) * 233);   


//money bar progress 2 (li_montant_recu=1) 
$p_two=$db->query("SELECT * FROM leve_invest WHERE li_montant_recu=1 AND li_leve_id='".$l_r["l_id"]."'");

while($p_two_r=$p_two->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    $amount_p_two[]=$p_two_r["li_montant_hors_com"];
}

$p_two_sum=round((array_sum($amount_p_two) / $l_r["m_s"]) * 233);
```

So  `array $amount_p_one[]` and  `$amount_p_two[]` keeps on adding amounts, what i need is to make those arrays variables.

Comment: Why not just aggregate the amounts in your query?

Comment: the classic X Y question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why don't you just do something like:

```
$p_one = $db->query("SELECT SUM(li_montant_hors_com) AS p_one FROM leve_invest WHERE (li_montant_recu=0 OR li_montant_recu=1) AND li_leve_id='".$l_r["l_id"]."'");

$p_two = $db->query("SELECT SUM(li_montant_hors_com) AS p_two FROM leve_invest WHERE li_montant_recu=1 AND li_leve_id='".$l_r["l_id"]."'");
```

...as they say, "let the database do the work."

Comment: thank you !, this did the job and less code than my solution, the closeCursor() method threw an error.

Answer (score 1):

Try using [`closeCursor`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.closecursor.php) after each query. As explained in the PHP documentation on the function:

> **PDOStatement::closeCursor()** frees up the connection to the server so
>   that other SQL statements may be issued, but leaves the statement in a
>   state that enables it to be executed again.

Here is your code with `closeCursor()` lines included after each `while` query loop.

```
//money bar progress 1 (li_montant_recu=0 OR li_montant_recu=1) 
$p_one=$db->query("SELECT * FROM leve_invest WHERE (li_montant_recu=0 OR li_montant_recu=1) AND li_leve_id='".$l_r["l_id"]."'");

while($p_one_r=$p_one->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    $amount_p_one[]=$p_one_r["li_montant_hors_com"];
}

$p_one->closeCursor();

$p_one_sum=round((array_sum($amount_p_one) / $l_r["m_s"]) * 233);   


//money bar progress 2 (li_montant_recu=1) 
$p_two=$db->query("SELECT * FROM leve_invest WHERE li_montant_recu=1 AND li_leve_id='".$l_r["l_id"]."'");

while($p_two_r=$p_two->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    $amount_p_two[]=$p_two_r["li_montant_hors_com"];
}

$p_two->closeCursor();

$p_two_sum=round((array_sum($amount_p_two) / $l_r["m_s"]) * 233);
```

Comment: `$p_two_sum->closeCursor();` should be `$p_two->closeCursor();` - my edit was overwritten by yours....and now it's fine ;)

Comment: why would you suggest this over doing it in the querry?